# Using Selenium, Python script to open Firefox, not going to URL provided

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

## Problem

I'm following of the examples listed on the documentation [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/#). Basically, just trying to get Selenium to open Firefox, take me to a site, make a query and then close the browser.

I've been running into an issue where Selenium will open the browser, but then not go to the specified website. In other cases, I receive an error, I should mention this error only appear after upgrading Selenium.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

- I'm using the latest version of Firefox, `54.0.1`
- I'm using Python version `2.7.11`
- And I have Selenium version `3.4.3`

### script.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo!' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

Comment: you download the geckodriver and set path of it. google it and you will find many posts for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, these were the steps I took to solve this issue.

- Updated Firefox to the latest version
- Updated Selenium as well
- Removed incorrect version of geckodriver from `bin` folder
- Updated xcode in App Store
- Used `brew install geckodriver` to get correct version into bin folder
- Used `brew link`
- Ran script.py